# Why would signals not get caught?

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, posix, signals

At the very beginning of my main(), I have:

```
signal(SIGTERM, SIGTERM_handler);
```

SIGTERM_handler is:

```
void SIGTERM_handler(int signum) {

    NSLog(@"Caught signal: [%d]. Cleaning up ...",signum);
    //cleanup();
    NSLog(@"Done cleaning up. Exiting ...");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Those lines are never printed. When I set breakpoints in the handler, they are never hit. I don't call `sigaction()` anywhere. GDB is setup to pass through the signals I care about (either `handle SIGTERM SIGINT pass stop print` or `handle SIGTERM SIGINT pass nostop print`). Even the default signal handler isn't working - sending SIGINT (for which I have not specified a handler) to the program also does nothing.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is it possible the log file buffer isn't getting flushed?

Comment: How do you send the signal to your process when it's running in gdb? I would suggest trying one of the other signals (say kill -1 or kill -2)

Comment: I'm sending signals with `kill -2`, `kill -15` and others. I know that is working because if I turn do "handle ... stop", then GDB does indeed stop and say my program received a signal; it still does not fire the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shawn, so you're using CZMQ, which diverts the signals for its own purposes whenever you do a zctx_new(). My advice is if possible to let CZMQ do its thing and trap the interrupt using the mechanisms it provides, which are the global zctx_interrupted variable, and in any blocking ZMQ call, a null return and EINTR error code.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Objective C but I do have experience with signal handlers, so I'll answer as if for POSIX and C.

Calling any function that is not documented as "async signal safe" in a signal handler is a risk and should be avoided.  You cannot make any assumptions about the stack or any other state when the signal handler is called.  The stack might even be "trashed" (in the middle of creation or destruction of a frame) when your signal handler is called.  Your libraries might have inconsistent state when your signal handler is called.

Declare a volatile flag (int) that gets checked in your event loop, or whatever, to see if it has changed.  The signal handler should ONLY set that flag and return, nothing else.  (Unless your platform does SVR4-style signals, in which case you also need to re-install the signal handler within the signal handler.)

The log messages and other activity in response to the signal should be done by whatever code checks the flag and processes the event implied by the flag.

The symptoms you are seeing might not be due to the library calls in the signal handler (my money would honestly be on gdb interaction), but I definitely recommend taking all library calls out of the signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to have something to do with czmq's [`zsocket_new`](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual%3azsocket). Switching to [`zctx__socket_new`](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual%3azctx) fixed it. I haven't yet dug in to find out exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in a debugger?  I've hit issues with signals being handled differently on iOS platform inside and outside of a launching from GDB.  I think the same issue occurs in OSX.  It's been a long time and I can't give you specifics